# Prevent sharing the y-axis in a relplot

Tags: python, seaborn, facet-grid, relplot

I'm having trouble getting seaborn's `relplot` function to plot with different y axes on each row (while sharing x axes per column).

I can see that both the `FacetGrid` and `catplot` methods in seaborn have a sharex/sharey keyword argument that would solve my problem, but I can't find a similar one in `relplot`.

Is there some way I can work around this if it's intended by accessing the subplots returned by `relplot` individually? I would like to continue using relplot as it handles figure sizing perfectly while `FacetGrid` has a lot of issues in that area. Thanks.

Comment: A `relplot` creates a `FacetGrid`, so it's not clear why there would be issues with one, but not the other. In any case the `replot` has a `facet_kws` argument, which allows to provide further arguments to the underlying `FacetGrid`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

This can be done by passing a dictionary with `FacetGrid` keyword arguments to `relplot`, like this:

```
facet_kws={'sharey': False, 'sharex': True}
```

(See [seaborn.relplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) documentation.)

Answer (score 2):

To share axes across rows or columns, you can specify `'row'` or `'col'` instead of the bool for the facet_kws, such as:

```
facet_kws={'sharey': 'row', 'sharex': True}
```