# How to convert data from wide to long so values are plotted against time

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, time-series, seaborn

I have a time series data set of multiple IDs and multiple variables, each variable has 3 time series entries - "baseline", "3 month", "6 month". The dataframe is structured like this, df =

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'Patient ID': [11111, 11111, 11111, 11111, 22222, 22222, 22222, 22222, 33333, 33333, 33333, 33333, 44444, 44444, 44444, 44444, 55555, 55555, 55555, 55555],
        'Lab Attribute': ['% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)', '% Saturation- Iron', 'ALK PHOS', 'ALT(SGPT)', 'AST (SGOT)'],
        'Baseline': [46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0, 46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0, 46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0, 46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0, 46.0, 94.0, 21.0, 18.0],
        '3 Month': [23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0, 23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0, 23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0, 23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0, 23.0, 82.0, 13.0, 17.0],
        '6 Month': [34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0, 34.0, 65.0, 10.0, 14.0]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

    Patient ID       Lab Attribute  Baseline  3 Month  6 Month
0        11111  % Saturation- Iron      46.0     23.0     34.0
1        11111            ALK PHOS      94.0     82.0     65.0
2        11111           ALT(SGPT)      21.0     13.0     10.0
3        11111          AST (SGOT)      18.0     17.0     14.0
4        22222  % Saturation- Iron      46.0     23.0     34.0
5        22222            ALK PHOS      94.0     82.0     65.0
6        22222           ALT(SGPT)      21.0     13.0     10.0
7        22222          AST (SGOT)      18.0     17.0     14.0
8        33333  % Saturation- Iron      46.0     23.0     34.0
9        33333            ALK PHOS      94.0     82.0     65.0
10       33333           ALT(SGPT)      21.0     13.0     10.0
11       33333          AST (SGOT)      18.0     17.0     14.0
12       44444  % Saturation- Iron      46.0     23.0     34.0
13       44444            ALK PHOS      94.0     82.0     65.0
14       44444           ALT(SGPT)      21.0     13.0     10.0
15       44444          AST (SGOT)      18.0     17.0     14.0
16       55555  % Saturation- Iron      46.0     23.0     34.0
17       55555            ALK PHOS      94.0     82.0     65.0
18       55555           ALT(SGPT)      21.0     13.0     10.0
19       55555          AST (SGOT)      18.0     17.0     14.0
```

What I'm trying to do is group by the ID and Lab Attribute and create a plot of each "Lab Attribute" - % Saturation- Iron, ALK PHOS, etc., that will include the time series for all of the Patient IDs.

So based on the example data there would be 4 plots - % Saturation- Iron, ALK PHOS, etc., that each would contain 5 traces (1 for each ID).

I tried using groupby per this article - [Creating a time-series plot with data in long format in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682819/creating-a-time-series-plot-with-data-in-long-format-in-python)

Though it just plots everything on one chart.

This is the code I have so far:

```
df_labs = pd.read_csv("/Users/johnconor/Documents/Python/gut_microbiome/out/nw_labs_up_to_6mon.csv")
df_labs = df_labs.fillna(method='ffill')

dfl = df_labs.groupby(['Patient_ID', 'Lab_Attribute'])['Baseline','3 Month','6 Month'].sum().plot()
```

This was the outcome:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

Part of the problem I'm having is that all of the examples I can find have long format data with only 1 values column. Not a number of values over time.

I also tried to utilize the approach for multiple plots per this article - [Creating a time-series plot with data in long format in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66682819/creating-a-time-series-plot-with-data-in-long-format-in-python)

```
n_ids = df_labs.Patient_ID.unique().size
n_cols = int(n_ids ** 0.5)
n_rows = n_cols + (1 if n_ids % n_cols else 0)                   
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols)
axes = axes.ravel()
for i, (id, att, base,three,six) in enumerate(df_labs.groupby(['Patient_ID', 'Lab_Attribute'])['Baseline','3 Month','6 Month'].sum().reset_index()):
    print(idx)
    series.plot(ax=axes[i], title=f"ID:{idx}")
fig.tight_layout()
```

Though am running into issues as it is again designed for only 1 set of values. Producing the error:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-42cf5bc14bdb> in <module>
      4 fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows, n_cols)
      5 axes = axes.ravel()
----> 6 for i, (id, att, base,three,six) in enumerate(df_labs.groupby(['Patient_ID', 'Lab_Attribute'])['Baseline','3 Month','6 Month'].sum().reset_index()):
      7     print(idx)
      8     series.plot(ax=axes[i], title=f"ID:{idx}")

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 5)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The shape of the dataframe should be changed to a long form using [`.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), which will allow the month to be used as a time axis.
- It will be easiest to use [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html) with `kind='line'`, to create the visualization.

  - Change `col`, `row`, and/or `hue` to adjust how the data should be grouped. Do not change `x` and `y`.
- To prevent sharing `y`, see [Prevent Sharing of Y Axes in Seaborn Relplot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56363662/7758804)

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# reshape the dataframe
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['Patient ID', 'Lab Attribute'], var_name='Months')

# change the Months values to numeric
dfm.Months = dfm.Months.map({'Baseline': 0, '3 Month': 3, '6 Month': 6})

# display(dfm.head())
   Patient ID       Lab Attribute  Months  value
0       11111  % Saturation- Iron       0   46.0
1       11111            ALK PHOS       0   94.0
2       11111           ALT(SGPT)       0   21.0
3       11111          AST (SGOT)       0   18.0
4       22222  % Saturation- Iron       0   46.0

# plot a figure level line plot with seaborn
p = sns.relplot(data=dfm, col='Lab Attribute', x='Months', y='value', hue='Patient ID', kind='line', col_wrap=4, marker='o', palette='husl')
```

- The lines are stacked because the data values are all the same

[image]

- Use [`seaborn.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with `kind='bar'` for a bar plot visualization

```py
p = sns.catplot(data=dfm, col='Lab Attribute', x='Months', y='value', hue='Patient ID', kind='bar', col_wrap=4)
```

[image]